# Redirecting Multiple stdins?

Tags: bash, sorting, redirect, input, stdin

I have three files named One, Two, Three.

One contains:

```
1
3
2
```

Two contains:

```
4
6
5
```

Three contains:

```
7
9
8
```

When I give the following command:

```
$sort < One < Two < Three
```

I get the output:

```
7
8
9
```

But when I give the following command:

```
$sort One Two Three
```

I get the ouput:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Can anyone please shed light on what exaclty is happening here? Why does the input from 1 and 2 not taken into consideration in the first command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command is the same as:

```
sort 0<1 0<2 0<3
```

(file descriptor 0 is standard input)

Redirections are processed in the order they appear, from left to right.
`sort` command itself cannot see any of those files.
`bash` open file `1`,`2`,`3` at `file descriptor 0` one by one.
So the right most one override left ones.
At last, `sort` read from `file descriptor 0` which is bind to file `3`.

Comment: Thats the explanation I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You can't redirect multiple files with bash. To work around this limitation you could use cat:

```
cat 1 2 3 | sort
```

On a side note, zsh supports what it calls mutlios:

```
 zsh$ setopt multios
 zsh$ sort < 1 < 2 < 3 > 4 > 5
 zsh$ tr '\n' ' ' < 4 < 5
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```