# Redirecting Multiple stdouts

Tags: bash, redirect, stdout

I have three files ina a directory named One, Two, Three.

One contains:

```
asdfg
```

Two contains:

```
qwerty
```

Three contains:

```
zxcvb
```

When I give the following command:

```
$ls > One > Two > Three
```

Then I give the following command:

```
$cat One
```

Output:

```
Nothing
```

Then I give the following command:

```
$cat Two
```

Output:

```
Nothing
```

Then I give the following command:

```
$cat Three
```

Output:

```
One
Three
Two
```

Can anyone please shed light on what exaclty is happening here? Why do the files One & Two become empty and the why does the output of the ls command get written only to the file Three?

Comment: we're left to guess what your real intent is. Please edit your question to include the expected output(s). Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371283/redirecting-multiple-stdins/12371634#12371634) `bash` doesn't support demultiplexing, and it doesn't support  multiplexing either. The effect that you're seeing is that each file is opened `O_TRUNC`, which means all content is destroyed. When multiple redirections are specified they're closed again right away, only the last redirection is kept and actually receives any data.

Here's an excerpt of `strace` running the command:

```
strace -f -e open,dup2,close bash -c 'ls > one > two > three'
```

```strace
...
open("one", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 1)                  = 1
close(3)                    = 0
open("two", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 1)                  = 1
close(3)                    = 0
open("three", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 1)                  = 1
close(3)                    = 0
...
```

As you can see bash keeps overwriting the same file descriptor. so only the last one will receive any data. One work around is to use `tee` which writes what it receives on `stdin` to all its arguments and `stdout`:

```
ls | tee One Two Three > /dev/null
```

On a side note, `zsh` does support this:

```
 zsh$ setopt multios
 zsh$ ls > One > Two > Three
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only redirect once. The first redirect opens the first file for writing (removing any previous contents), then closes it immediately when the next redirect overrides it.

You seem to be looking for the `tee` command.